# Implementing Blackberry Maps with MapLocation

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-maps

I want to display blackberry maps with markers for various location within my application. I tried using `net.rim.device.api.lbs.maps.ui.MapField` but it throws `IllegalArgumentException(Bitmap is too large)`

Anyone has tried implementing `net.rim.device.api.lbs.maps.ui.MapField` and setting the model with `Mappable` or `MapLocation` to display various locations?

All i'm trying to do is display map with multiple location markers. On click of markers it should display a details screen for that location.

Answer (score 0):

RichMapField map = MapFactory.getInstance().generateRichMapField();

MapDataModel modelMap = map.getModel();

// Your Locations

MapLocation julieHome = new MapLocation( 43.47751, -80.54817,"Julie - Home", null );

int julieHomeId = modelMap.add( (Mappable) julieHome, "julie" );

MapLocation paulHome = new MapLocation( 43.47551, -80.55335, "Paul - Home", null );

 int paulHomeId = modelMap.add( (Mappable) paulHome, "paul" );

 map.getMapField().update( true );